# fetch возвращает html вместо json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, fetch

хочу перезаписать запрос $ajax который возвращает json  на fetch, но fetch возвращает html. Подскажите какие настройки надо добавить в запросе или что я делаю не так

```html
$.ajax({
  url: "/project/data/",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);

  }
})


fetch("/project/data/")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверняка сервер отправляет html а не json

Comment: эти запросы не аналогичны?

Comment: datatype в $.ajax как пишут в документации устанавливает заголовок Accept, сервер вполне может на него ориентироваться. Откройте в консоли вкладку network и внимательно посмотрите какие заголовки отправляет первый и второй методы. Попробуйте при вызове второго метода передать такие же заголовки как готовит первый

Comment: в network  написано , что  content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 , хотя я добавил 'Content-Type': 'application/json' при вызове

Answer (score 1):

### [Использование `Fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```js
const fetchOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};

fetch("/project/data/", fetchOptions)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

Comment: ошибка осталась такая же

Comment: в network написано , что content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 , хотя я добавил 'Content-Type': 'application/json' при вызове как в Вашем примере

Comment: @АлександрРодин Я только что выполнил этот код, посмотрел в Network и увидел там `application/json`